# Вопрос по работе Timer и Textbox

Tags: c#

Мне нужно рандомно запускать метод, который будет читать с текстового файла строку  и выводить ее TextBox, пока строки в файле не закончатся. Получилось вот что.

```
 Random rand = new Random();
        Timer mytimer = new Timer();
        public void Timer()
        {

            mytimer.Tick += new EventHandler(Reader);
            mytimer.Interval = rand.Next(1000, 3000);
            mytimer.Enabled = true;
            mytimer.Start();

        }
        public int TotalLines()
        {
            using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(@"test.txt"))
            {
                int i = 0;
                while (r.ReadLine() != null) { i++; }
                return i;
            }
        }
        public void Reader(Object myObject, EventArgs myEventArgs)
        {
            StreamReader file = new StreamReader(@"test.txt");

            progressBar1.Maximum = TotalLines();
            for (int i = 0; i <= TotalLines(); i++)
            {
                textBox1.Text =  file.ReadLine();
                progressBar1.Value = i;

            }
            file.Close();
            mytimer.Interval = rand.Next(1000, 3000);


        }


        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Timer();
        }
```

Но с эти кодом проблемы, во первых в текстбоксе не отрисовывается строка, а во вторых таймер гоняет этот метод по кругу. Где я не прав?

С таймером я разобрался следующим образом

```
   public void Reader(Object myObject, EventArgs myEventArgs)
        {
            StreamReader file = new StreamReader(@"test.txt");
            int f = TotalLines();
            progressBar1.Maximum = f;
            for (int i = 0; i <= f; i++)
            {

                textBox1.Text =  file.ReadLine();
                progressBar1.Value = i;
                mytimer.Interval = rand.Next(1000, 3000);
                mytimer.Stop();
            }
            file.Close();

        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я бы вовсе отказался от старомодного таймера и многопоточности, и делал бы проще, через async/await.

Пример:

```
async Task Work(string filename, IProgress<double> progress, IProgress<string> produce)
{
    var rnd = new Random();
    progress.Report(0);

    var data = File.ReadLines(filename);
    var count = data.Count(); // внимание - может быть медленно!

    int i = 0;
    foreach (var line in data)
    {
        i++;
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(rnd.Next(1000, 3000)));
        produce.Report(line);
        progress.Report((double)i / count);
    }

    progress.Report(1);
}
```

Запускать можно, например, так:

```
async void OnGO(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Progress<double> progress = new Progress<double>(p => ProgressReport.Value = p);
    Progress<string> produce = new Progress<string>(s =>
                        Target.Text += (s + Environment.NewLine));
    GoButton.IsEnabled = false;
    await Work(FilenameBox.Text, progress, produce);
    GoButton.IsEnabled = true;
}
```

```
<Window x:Class="Test.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBox Name="Target"/>
        <ProgressBar Grid.Row="1" Name="ProgressReport" Height="15" Margin="10"
                     Minimum="0" Maximum="1"/>
        <DockPanel Grid.Row="2" LastChildFill="True">
            <Button Content="Go" Name="GoButton" Click="OnGO" Width="75"
                    DockPanel.Dock="Right" Margin="10"/>
            <TextBox Name="FilenameBox" Margin="10"/>
        </DockPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```